# Using "super" with "redirect_to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused how redirect_to works... In the code below, I have an authorize method that redirects no matter what (just as an example for my question, this has an if statement in my application).  Then in my UsersController, I want to extend the authorize method, and add some logic below it.

I get the error "undefined method `username` for nil:NilClass".  (well, a current_user isn't defined but there should be a redirect before this statement)

My question is, why is the code in the UsersController authorize method executing when a call to "super" should redirect no matter what, and that code should not be executed?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize

  def authorize
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Not authorized'
    return false
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def authorize
    super
    return true if current_user.username == 'admin'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to` does not stop the method call chain. You're just calling the method there which tells the controller to send back a redirect header. If you want your `authorize` method in your `UsersController` to work, it would need to be something like this:

```
super && current_user.username == 'admin'
```

And you would need to modify the `ApplicationController`'s `authorize` method to also return`true`. If `ApplicationController`'s `authorize` returns `true` and `current_user.username` also returns `true`, then this new code in your UsersController's `authorize` will also return `true`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Great :) Thanks for following my advice.